# Making dropdown selection to fill element without gaps

Tags: html, css, web, bulma

I use menu that was created by other developer in our  company. I add to the first item of the menu dropdown selection, but the problem that the dropdown box not fully fill the all  the item and I can't make it fill.

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="main-container-top-menu scroll1" id="main-container-top-menu">
    <div class="top-menu-item-container-empty">
      <div style="width: 50px"></div>
    </div>
    
    


    
    <div class="top-menu-item-container">
      <div class="inactive-border-bottom">
          <p class="control has-icons-left is-expanded">
          <span class="select is-fullwidth ">
            <select class="full-height">
              <option>dropdown</option>
              <option>options 1</option>
            </select>                  
          </span>
          <span class="icon is-small is-left"><i class="far fa-building"></i></span>
        </p> 
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="top-menu-item-container" >
        <div>
          <div class="top-menu-item">2. Lot and Model</div>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div class="top-menu-item-container" >
      <div [className]="ishpExpanded?'active-border-bottom':'inactive-border-bottom'">
        <div class="top-menu-item">3. Home Plan</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="top-menu-item-container">
      <div [className]="isupgExpanded?'active-border-bottom':'inactive-border-bottom'">
        <div class="top-menu-item">4. Upgrades</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="top-menu-item-container">
      <div [className]="isnextExpanded?'active-border-bottom':'inactive-border-bottom'">
        <div class="top-menu-item">5. Next Steps</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-menu-icon-container">
      <i class="fas fa-print top-menu-icon"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-share-alt top-menu-icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is CSS:

```
.scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 3px;
  }
  
  .scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #eff0f0;
  }
  
  .scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #666;
  }
  .main-container-top-menu {
    scrollbar-width: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
 
  }
  
  .top-menu-item-container-empty {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    border-right: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 350;
    user-select: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .top-menu-item-container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    border-right: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 350;
    user-select: none;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .active-border-bottom {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eb2028;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .inactive-border-bottom {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .top-menu-item-active {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #1d1d1d;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 350;
    user-select: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    stroke-width: 0.6px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.6px;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .top-menu-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 14px;
    user-select: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .top-menu-item-first {
    cursor: default;
    border-right: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    border-left: none;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: left;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .top-right-menu-item {
    /* margin-right: 50px; */
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eff0f0;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .top-item-logo {
    height: 55px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 55px;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  
  .top-menu-icon-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .top-menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 14px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  .left-arrow,
  .right-arrow {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .constructor-top-container {
      justify-content: center;
      padding-left: 3%;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1088px) {
    .top-right-menu-item {
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #eff0f0;
      flex: 1;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
    }
  
    .main-container-top-menu {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    .top-menu-icon {
      margin-right: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 14px;
      padding-top: 12px;
    }
    .scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
    }
  
    .scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #eff0f0;
    }
  
    .scroll1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #666;
    }
    .top-menu-item-first {
      padding-left: 35px;
    }
  
    .main-container-top-menu {
      transition: 0.2s all;
      min-height: 62px;
    }
    .top-item-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 62px;
      width: 62px;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  
    .left-arrow {
      height: 60px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background: white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #d1d1d1;
      top: 0px;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 5;
      padding-left: 7px;
    }
  
    .right-arrow {
      height: 60px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background: white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #b1b1b1;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      left: calc(100% - 88px);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1088px) {
    .main-container-top-menu {
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      /* display: block; */
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap !important;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    .main-container {
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
  }
  
  .no-suite-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
```

Workink [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5bmgs9z/)!

How can I make dropdown to fill the menuc without gaps?

### Update

Text moved to the left:

[image]

Comment: your problem is `padding`

Comment: is here - `.control.has-icons-left .input, .control.has-icons-left .select select {
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}`

Comment: Sergey, thanks for post, but my problem not with text inside the selection, I want the selection element to fill the parent element.

Comment: I corrected it. Like this? - https://ibb.co/0htshYp

Comment: or like this? - https://ibb.co/3shFKV7

Comment: Sorry Sergey for the delay, the second (ibb.co/3shFKV7),  is the desired one

Comment: Can you tell me please how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result, you need to do the following:

1. Remove `padding-left: 20px` and `padding-right: 20px` from the `.inactive-border-bottom` selector;
2. Add `height: 100%` to these selectors - `.control` and `.select.is-fullwidth`.
3. Need to register `.full-height` in your css, and write the rule `height: 100%!important` in it. `!important` is necessary because this rule overrides the `height: 2.5em` rule in the `.select select`.

Comment: thanks, awesome! is there any option to prevent moving text to left? I  want it in the center.

Comment: the text that appears in the dropdown list? show the screenshot please. since I have the text centered.

Comment: try `text-align-last: center` for `.select.is-fullwidth select`

Comment: always happy to help